# how to use IOS10 on xcode9?

Tags: xcode, ios10, ios11, xcode9

I have updated my xcode, and I want to run my apps on iPhone 5, but my iPhone 5 have the iOS10 and I the update the xcode use the iOS11 , and how can I use the iOS10 on xcode9?

Comment: Yes you can. Set the minimum version of your project to iOS 10

Comment: I redid the duplicate since the other two had nothing to do with this question. This question is about setting the app's Deployment Target.

Answer (score 15, accepted):

The project needs to have the minimum version set correctly,
Then download the ios10 simulators under

Xcode->Preferences->Components

Comment: The OP has a phone with iOS 10 so there is no need to download any simulators. Simply setting the Deployment Target is enough.

Comment: Thanks, it works!